# excel sheet Comparing two different columns if match copy its next two cells into new column

Tags: vba, excel

hey guys plz solve this...

[image]

So... i want to compare column D with A...
Here in example ...
D1 matches with A2 ... so i want B2 and C2 in E1 and F1 respectively ....
D2 matches with A6 ... so i want B6 and C6 in E2 and F2 respectively ....
i have a recode of 2022 in A column to be compared with D...
so i want a one formula dat can fulfill my desire in one shot by selecting comparing columns...
*thanks in advance*

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use index match formula together to achieve that. 
In E1 cell write below formula

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH($D1,$A:$A,0)),"")
```

In F1 cell write below formula **(You can also fill right above formula)**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH($D1,$A:$A,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Loop and Find

```
Sub SendToRange()
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, x As Range, c As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, "D"), Cells(Rws, "D"))
    Columns("E:F").ClearContents

    For Each x In rng.Cells
        Set c = Range("A:A").Find(what:=x, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then

            r = c.Row
            Range(Cells(x.Row, "E"), Cells(x.Row, "F")).Value = Range(Cells(r, 2), Cells(r, 3)).Value
        Else:
            Range(Cells(x.Row, "E"), Cells(x.Row, "F")).Value = "N/A"

        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
1st column=vlookup(D1,$A$1:$A$n,2,false)
2nd clumn =vlookup(D1,$A$1:$A$n,3,false)
```

Comment: Hi there, the formula you have shown is not correct,`=vlookup(D1,$A$1:$A$n,2,false)` columns should go from column A to B or C